# What does the ethics of X mean?

Tags: word-usage

I have seen this phrasing used for a movie, a book. How can a narrative have ethics? Is this a shorthand for the ethics of the author of X?

Comment: Could you give an example of this usage?

Comment: 'a boo'? What is that?

Comment: @Mitch "Take a boo at this." Take a look at this. As used [here](https://globalnews.ca/news/3830410/western-university-offers-chance-to-take-a-boo-at-the-moon/).(It may have come from *peek-a-boo* but I'm not sure.) However, I don't understand its role in the question.

Comment: Ah, unless it's just a typo for *book* . . .

Comment: Kristoffer, can you add any details, preferably the actual quote, and any extra context. Also 'boo'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'ethics of X' where X is a book, movie, etc. means the ethical values espoused or portrayed in the work.

Works of art generally display ethical values to a greater or lesser extent. Specifically art, especially narrative, generally shows some actions as 'good' and some as 'bad'. Even if the work portrays no actions as being inherently good or bad, then that itself is a portrayal of ethical values.

For example the "Ethics of Star Trek" might include not interfering in other culture's development<sup>1</sup>, treating life forms equally, etc. The ethics of a Disney movie might be "Believe in yourself and everything will be OK".

Other uses of 'ethics of X' include where X is a field of study or activity, for example "ethics of medicine" means ethics related to medical study or practice.

[1] Unless you have a good reason, such as being Captain Kirk.